# A row of zeroes is added to an array instead of the row I want

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array which I'm doing some calculations on. The array begins as

```
e = array([[1,2,1,3],
           [3,-1,-3,-1],
           [2,3,1,4]])
```

I modify it a bit to convert it to:

```
array([[  1,   2,   1,   3],
      [  0,  -7,  -6, -10],
      [  0,  -1,  -1,  -2]])
```

Then I run this code on it:

```
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction

def ref(x):
    dimension = x.shape
    row_counter = 1
    first_values = [x[i][row_counter] for i in range(dimension[0])]                               #gets a list of elements of the column
    first_values = [number != 0 for number in first_values]                                       #0 is a pivot element?
    if False in first_values:                                                                     
        true_index =  first_values.index(True); false_index =   first_values.index(False)
        if true_index > false_index:                                                               #not any more
            x[[false_index, true_index]] = x[[true_index, false_index]]

    for i in range(row_counter+1,dimension[0]):
        multiplier = Fraction(x[row_counter][row_counter], x[i][row_counter])**-1
        row1 = multiplier*x[row_counter]
        row1 = x[i]-row1
        print row1
        x[i] = row1   

return x
```

Running this returns:

```
[0 0 -1/7 -4/7]
array([[  1,   2,   1,   3],
         [  0,  -7,  -6, -10],
         [  0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

So the result should be

```
array([[  1,   2,   1,   3],
         [  0,  -7,  -6, -10],
         [  0, 0, -1/7, -4/7]])
```

It prints the correct row entry but it doesn't get added to the array, and a row of zeroes is added instead. Could someone please tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `numpy` arrays are homogeneous with specific types.  For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

When you set an element or slice specifically, what you add gets coerced to the current `dtype`, so:

```
>>> a[0] = 5
>>> a
array([5, 2, 3])
```

but

```
>>> a[0] = 4.3
>>> a
array([4, 2, 3])
```

You can get upcasting when you're not acting in-place and so `numpy` is going to have to make a copy (i.e. a new object) anyway:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a + 4.3
array([ 5.3,  6.3,  7.3])
>>> (a + 4.3).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

In your case, you can get the behaviour you want if you start with a `numpy` array of dtype `object`:

```
>>> e = np.array([[  1,   2,   1,   3],
...               [  0,  -7,  -6, -10],
...               [  0,  -1,  -1,  -2]], dtype=object)
>>> 
>>> ref(e)
array([[1, 2, 1, 3],
       [0, -7, -6, -10],
       [0, 0, -1/7, -4/7]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used numpy before and didn't realize I had to specify the `dtype`.

Comment: @user1709173: you usually don't -- I rarely have to, because I usually work with `float` numpy arrays and stay there -- but if you're going to use a general Python object that isn't one of numpy's preferred types then you probably will.